# Ignore collision between specific models

Tags: collision

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to ignore collision between two objects ? Like an object passes through another specific object, but keeps the collision with the environment (other models and ground).

Thanks in avdance :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8921/ignore-collision-between-specific-models/) by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 78 on 2015-06-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

you can use the [`<collide_bitmask>`](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.5&elem=collision#contact_collide_bitmask) tag in the `collision`.

Here is the [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=collide_bitmask&cat=physics).

However you need the latest gazebo (v.6) in order to work. Meaning you need to install from source using the default branch for now.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2015-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [djou07](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/969/djou07/) on 2015-06-15**:
thanks a lot for your answer.